# iOS 5 - Include chat within application

Tags: objective-c, ios5, chat

I am developing a iOS 5 application and we have to include a chat application within it.

- The chat have to show the messages and the list of connected users (users in the chat tab in the app).
- There are two types of users (normal users and administrators).
- An user is tagged as administrator in the CMS. The administrators can kick, ban, unban and delete messages.
- All the users can send messages to a chat window.
- There are not private chats.
- Users can select a text in the chat and for example call the dictionary to search a word.

One option is to use sockets, as explained in http://www.raywenderlich.com/3932/how-to-create-a-socket-based-iphone-app-and-server. The problem with that is that it creates a socket connection with each person connected to the server. I think that I don't need that.
Maybe a best option is to make the connected users to poll the server for new messages.  I think it might be another solution which I dont have to code all myself.

I have examined this jabber client for iOS:  http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/building-a-jabber-client-for-ios-xmpp-integration/ 
The problem with that is that I have a Rails backend and It will be a lot of work to include that server in my rails application.

Does anyone know any third party libraries to include a chat within iOS application? Any tips or guidelines? This is a pretty standard problem and It should be some standard libraries that I can't find.

Any experience with node.js or nowjs?

Thanks!

Comment: What search terms did you use to search for third party libraries already?

Comment: I have searched for ios chat library integration. I found some Jabber clients but I think that it doesnt fit my needs.

Comment: Because your question doesn't include anything that indicates you've put any effort toward finding the answer yourself.  What libraries have you examined?  Why is Jabber insufficient?  What chat protocols have you looked at?  Why won't they work for you?  Or, it sounds like, “I have these very specific requirements for my application.  Won't you please find me a library that does exactly what I want?  Or post a bunch of sample code that solves my problem for me?”

Comment: Ok, I will put some research that I have made but I didn't included that because I want an open answer from different perspectives.